# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0 for offline project

Tags: spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have intranet environment where I am developing springboot Application. My m2 repository does not have

```
exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0.
```

But When I added it as a dependency and plugin. The error remains the same.

How to solve this error? I find it difficult as I can't use internet. Please help for setting up the development environment.